# How to create three subplots where the height of the upper plot is lower?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, legend, subplot

I would like to create a plot that consists of three subplots, where the upper left plot has the same width as the lower left plot but 1/3 of the height. Besides, I'd also like to plot the legend in the upper right area from the lower left plot. Is this even possible?

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, figsize = (16,9))
ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((2,3), (1,0), colspan=2)
ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((2,3), (1,2), colspan=1)
ax3 = plt.subplot2grid((2,3), (0,0), colspan=2)
fig.suptitle('Title')
fig.tight_layout()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.gridspec import GridSpec
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi)
y1 = np.cos(x)
y2 = np.sin(x)

fig = plt.figure()
gs = GridSpec(2, 2, width_ratios=[2, 1], height_ratios=[1, 3])
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0])
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs[1])
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(gs[2])
ax4 = fig.add_subplot(gs[3])

ax3.plot(x, y1, label="cos")
ax3.plot(x, y2, label="sin")
handles, labels = ax3.get_legend_handles_labels()

# hide axis on the top left subplot
ax2.axis("off")
# adding two legends
legend1 = ax2.legend([handles[0]], [labels[0]], loc="upper left")
legend2 = ax2.legend([handles[1]], [labels[1]], loc="lower right")
ax2.add_artist(legend1)

plt.tight_layout()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your solution. I tried this and it works fine, but as soon as I then use fig.tight_layout() then everything moves again. How can I incorporate tight_layout?

Comment: that helps for sure! Is there also a way I can divide the legend into two? So that I technically have cos in the upper left corner of ax2 and sin in lower right corner of ax2 as two separate legends?

Comment: I have updated again the answer with your request. Please, mark this answer as the solution to your question :)

Comment: Many thanks for all your input! As a final question: Is there a way to make y-axes of ax3 and ax4 the same. Sometimes people use plt.subplots(sharey= True) but how can you do that here for only ax3 and ax4?

Comment: You need to change `ax4 = fig.add_subplot(gs[3], sharey=ax3)` and hide the yticks with `plt.setp(ax4.get_yticklabels(), visible=False)`.

Comment: But in this way you still have the ticks on the ax4 plot but they don't have a number. I would also like to take out the tick line.

Comment: Set `ax4.tick_params(axis="y", left=False)`.